# Building a Mender Yocto image for a Raspberry

Tags: image, raspberry-pi, updates, yocto, mender

I'm trying to build a **Mender Yocto image** for my **Raspberry Pi** to have the  possibility of remote updates.

I was following this instructions:
 https://docs.mender.io/1.0/artifacts/building-mender-yocto-image

Also, I added this layer:
https://github.com/mendersoftware/meta-mender/tree/master/meta-mender-raspberrypi

My *`local.conf`* looks like:

```
KERNEL_IMAGETYPE = "uImage"

MENDER_PARTITION_ALIGNMENT_KB = "4096"
MENDER_BOOT_PART_SIZE_MB = "40"
IMAGE_DEPENDS_sdimg += " bcm2835-bootfiles"
# raspberrypi files aligned with mender layout requirements
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES_append = " boot.scr u-boot.bin;${SDIMG_KERNELIMAGE}"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " kernel-image kernel-devicetree"
MENDER_ARTIFACT_NAME = "release-1"
INHERIT += "mender-full"
MACHINE = "raspberrypi3"

DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""

IMAGE_FSTYPES = "ext4"
```

My *`bblayers.conf`* file looks like:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
/home/c3po/poky/meta \
/home/c3p0/poky/meta-poky \
/home/c3po/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
/home/c3po/poky/oe-meta-go \
/home/c3po/poky/meta-mender/meta-mender-core \
/home/c3po/poky/meta-mender/meta-mender-demo \
/home/c3po/poky/meta-mender/meta-mender-raspberrypi \
"
```

In additon to the answer from Drew I added:

In the poky folder I cloned the  meta-raspberrypi layer:

```
git clone  git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi
```

Than I added the layer with:

```
bitbake-layers add-layer /meta-raspberrypi
```

and the dependencies

```
git clone git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core
git clone git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded

add-layer ../openembedded-core
add-layer ../meta-openembedded
```

Comment: What is the actual error or the actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have the platform layer in your configuration.  See https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-raspberrypi/ for more details.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense.

Comment: Mender has also recently announced official support for the Raspberry Pi 3 platform so it should be easier moving forward to get that platform up and running.  More details here: https://mender.io/blog/mender-1-3-beta-raspberry-pi-3